# Equal button height for RelativeLayout (while still filling up all space)

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have an Android application that goes about like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toplayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.90" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1_of_10"
            android:layout_width="70dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/text_0x1701" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_2_of_10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_1_of_10"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button_1_of_10"/>

        <!--Another 8 buttons-->

    <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentpane"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_1_of_10" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout 
        android:id="@+id/actionbuttonslayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.10">
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I need the 10 buttons to fill up the entire height from the top to the footer (the 0.1 weighted RelativeLayout), while all the buttons keep an equal height. However, I want to know whether there is a kind of equivalent to the layout_weight from LinearLayout, but for RelativeLayouts, as it's not performant to have nested weights in LinearLayouts. I'm not really looking for other solutions, because I still have some thing to try, but I want to know whether or not this is possible?

My question, just to be clear, is: Is it possible to have an amount of Buttons with an equal height in a RelativeLayout and at the same time fill up all the available space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use weight you need to use a LinearLayout, just make a linear layout with the buttons take the space you want and then on each button inside have `android:layout_height="0dp"`  and also a `android:layout_weight="1"`

You don't need to sum all the weights to 1, just think of items with the same weight have the same size

Comment: Yeah, i know that I cant use weights in a RelativeLayout, but i dont want to nest all to many linearLayouts, as its bad for performance. Is there any way to do this without a LinearLayout?

Comment: It's bad to nest too many layouts, but in your case you would just change from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout. In either case your xml layout tree is just 3 levels deep, no need to optimize yet.